# sqlite error, reading value as column

Tags: sql, python-2.7, sqlite

hey experts I am trying to add value to specific column in table but python reading my value as column.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('ddbinven')

c = conn.cursor()
def insert_data(name,value):
    c.execute('INSERT INTO testingddb(%s) VALUES(%s);' %(name,value))
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()

insert_data("tablename", "reverseeng02")
```

error:

```
    c.execute('INSERT INTO testingddb(%s) VALUES(%s);' %(name,value))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: reverseeng02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found issue missing `""` around `%s`

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('ddbinven')

c = conn.cursor()
def insert_data(name,value):
    c.execute('INSERT INTO testingddb("%s") VALUES("%s");' %(name,value))
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```